# How to Get POST Request JSON then Change The JSON Format with Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an incoming Post request in JSON format like this:

```
[{"username":"ali","hair_color":"brown","height":1.2},{"username":"marc","hair_color":"blue","height":1.4},{"username":"zehua","hair_color":"black","height":1.8}]
```

and I want to change it into this format, and then send it to a RESTFUL API:

```
{"h":["username","hair_color","height"],"d":[["ali","brown",1.2],["marc","blue",1.4],["zehua","black",1.8]]}
```

The question is How to change the JSON format regardless different parameter names, "`h`" is for the parameter names and "`d`" is for the values?

---

Below is my js code:

```
var express = require("express");
var myParser = require("body-parser");
var app = express();

app.use(myParser.urlencoded({extended : true}));
app.use(myParser.json());

app.post("/parseJSON", function(request, response) {
    console.log(request.body); //This prints the JSON document received (if it is a JSON document)
    if(request.body.constructor === Object && Object.keys(request.body).length === 0)
    {
        response.end("-1");
    }
    else
    {
        response.end("0");
    }
});
app.get("/parseJSON", function(request, response) {
    console.log(request.body); //This prints the JSON document received (if it is a JSON document)
    if(request.body.constructor === Object && Object.keys(request.body).length === 0)
    {
        response.end("-1");
    }
    else
    {
        response.end("0");
    }
});

app.listen(8080);
```

Comment: Hi! already edit my question. Please check it out and kindly give me an answer to this problem @Ankh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you try it?

```
var key = Object.keys(request.body[0])
var data = request.body.map(ele => {
 return Object.values(ele);
})
var result = {h:key,d:data};
```

or

```
const h = Object.keys(request.body[0])
const d = request.body.map(ele => Object.values(ele))  // Use ES7 to enable using Object.values()

const result = {h, d};
```